# Excel File not Visible but Word file is

Tags: vba, excel

Form Workbook1 I'm launching the Opening_File Userform using the following code to keep the application hide and the form visible:

```
Sub ShowingForm()
    Opening_File.Show (vbModeless)
    Application.Visible = False
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
End Sub
```

and I use the following code to open Excel and Word Files from the form:

```
Sub OpeningExcelFile()
    Dim Finfo As String
    Dim FilterIndex As Integer
    Dim Title As String
    Dim Filename As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim objWdApp As Object
    Dim objWdDoc As Object



    'Setup the list of file filters
    Finfo = "Excel Files (*.xlsx),*xlsx," & _
            "Macro-Enable Worksheet (*.xlsm),*xlsm," & _
            "Word Files (*.docx),*.docx," & _
            "All Files (*.*),*.*"
             MultiSelect = True


    'Display *.* by default
    FilterIndex = 4

    'Set the dialog box caption
    Title = "Select a File to Open"

    'Get the Filename
    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(Finfo, _
        FilterIndex, Title)

    'Handle return info from dialog box

    If Filename = False Then
            MsgBox "No file was selected."
            Exit Sub 

    Else
        MsgBox "You selected " & Filename
    End If


    If InStr(1, Filename, ".docx", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Set objWdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objWdApp.Visible = True
        Set objWdDoc = objWdApp.Documents.Open(Filename) '\\ Open Word Document

    Else
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename) '\\ Open Excel Spreadsheet



    End If


End Sub
```

Opening Word files is not a problem but whenever I open Excel Files since `Application.Visible = False`, I have to Hide the form with :

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
     Opening_File.Hide
     Application.Visible = True
     ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
End Sub
```

So I'm able to see the excel file opened. Is there anyway to keep the form visible with the workbook where I'm launching the form not visible but every workbook I open from the form visible? Thank you

Comment: Why don't you open the other workbooks in a different instance of Excel, just like you are doing with the Word documents.  (I hope you are correctly closing those other instances of Word when you finish with them.)

Comment: The form would have a similar function as a toolbar or quick access toolbar from witch the user would be able to perform different kind of options or actions available from one single place. I prefer to be able to Open a new instance or a existence excel file  from the user form

Comment: Not sure I'm following as to why what you are trying to do can't be achieved with the workbook in a different instance of Excel.  Just as you will have things on your form that interact with `objWdDoc`, you could have things that interact with `wb` even if `wb` is in a different instance of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I realize the best way to go in this kind of situations is to leave the         `ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False` witch would leave the application visible and also will allow me to see each workbook file opened from the form.

```
Sub ShowingForm()
    Opening_File.Show (vbModeless)
    Application.Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
End Sub
```